# cakePHP not adding aro on user/group add

Tags: cakephp, acl

I am trying to get aco's / aro's up and running on an application of mine. The cakePHP tutorial says that when I add a user, it should automatically be added to the aros table, but it's not working.

User model

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    public $belongsTo = array('Group');
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter(); 
            $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('*');
    }

    public function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
            $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
        } else {
            $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
        }
        if (!$groupId) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
        }
    }   
    public function afterSave() {
        $this->Aro->create();
        $this->Aro->save(array('alias'=>$this->field('username')));
    }       
}
```

Shouldn't the line

```
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));
```

perform the cakePHP magic and create the ARO automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database has tables called 'groups' and 'users', I believe the code in afterSave() is unnecessary.  Once `$actsAs` is set, you should not have to call any Aro methods.